# TouchableOpacity not being able to press on some corners

Tags: react-native

I am using react native with some views, scrollviews and touchableopacitys so I can click on the item and it takes me somewhere but from what I can see it can't be clicked on the corner[image]

Does anyone know why that might be?

```
<LearnCard
          title={"What is CBT?"}
          excerpt={"Learn more about CBT and how it can benefit you."}
          image={<WhatIsCBT />}
          content={`Cognitive Behavioural Therapy or CBT is type of talking therapy that can 
              help you to change the way you think and behave in your everyday life. 
              Whilst CBT therapy can be administered by a practitioner, many of the 
              techniques can be practiced on a daily basis by yourself, enabling you to 
              become your own expert in making practical changes to improve your 
              state of mind. \n
              CBT has been proven to work by over a 1,000 studies and can be effective
              in helping individuals with a number of issues, including anxiety, 
              depression, panic disorder and sleep problems. It's based on the idea that 
              our thoughts, feelings and actions are connected. CBT aims to help you 
              manage overwhelming and negative feelings by offering ways to reflect 
              and challenge them, breaking down negative patterns that keep us feeling
              low. \n
              CBT focuses on the present here-and-now, helping you to find coping 
              mechanisms for challenging situations, whilst relieving negative 
              symptoms. Through regularly utilising the tools offered in our Pocket CBT, 
              you will be able to better recognise your own unhealthy thinking patterns, 
              create new coping mechanisms for stressful situations and feel a stronger 
              sense of mental wellbeing.`}
        />
        <LearnCard
          title={"Practicing gratitude"}
          excerpt={"Acknowledging positive thoughts and feelings."}
          image={<PractisingGratitude />}
          content={`A big part of CBT involves acknowledging positive thoughts and feelings, 
          as well as challenging the negative ones. Practicing gratitude can have a 
          significant on our mental health and positivity. \n
          Try using the 'Practicing Gratitude' section of Pocket CBT to record 
          anything that you notice about your day that you're grateful for. This 
          might be something big, like being grateful for your children, or something
          small, like your morning coffee. \n
          Noticing these moments of being grateful or happy can help us to rewire 
          our brains to develop a more optimistic mindset, naturally placing a 
          stronger focus on the positive parts of our life, and less on the negative.\n`}
        />
```

```
<View style={styles.guidecardbigContainer}>
      <View style={{ width: 312, height: 120 }}>{image}</View>

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
          width: width - 40,
          marginTop: 15,
        }}
      >
        <View>
          ...
        </View>

        <View style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end", marginBottom: 6 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.primaryBtnContainer, {width: 104, height: 44}]} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CardViewer", { text: content, title: title })}>
            <Text style={[styles.primaryText, {fontSize: 16}]}>Learn</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

I tried changing the code from a map to normal code but it seems to be continuing

Comment: Hello! Maybe the problem is on the font used in styles for a component from `CardViewer` page. Please, verify if the font is with the correct name on property `fontFamily` or if the font is added to the project

Comment: @marcelofreires - The font isn't the issue because only the first button isn't able to be clicked while the rest can be clicked just fine wherever I want

Comment: Please, can you share the link to your project to see all the code or add the code from `CardViewer` page? I can't see any problem with the code above